# PHP: How to output validation status of register script without waiting for an email to be sent?

Tags: php

I have a registration form on my site. The form is sent to the server via AJAX and is then validated. Then it will output an address for the browser to be redirected to, if it was validated as valid information. PHP will then send a validation email to the email specified. The problem is that the sending of the email takes 10 seconds, and I don't want my users to wait for 10 seconds from they press Register to they get redirected...

Is there a way for PHP to tell the client the information was correctly validated and output the redirection URL, and continue sending the email without the client waiting?

Comment: I don't think PHP itself can do that (seeing how PHP is a scripting language and all), however if you had some sort of processing daemon, that one could parse the database every x seconds and send the E-Mails you store 'for sending' in a database.

Comment: Well, first of all I would strongly advise you to look into why your message is taking 10 seconds to send. Are you sending through a very slow remote SMTP service?

Comment: @ColinMorelli I'm using my own GMail account over SMTP to send the mails..

Comment: @ColinMorelli Though I haven't tested if it's Google or SwiftMail which is slow... I send attachments on 200KB with this email.

Comment: I' m not sure if I understand the problem. But AJAX can be used to send and receive data. Why don't you return a "success-message", redirect on success and then send the email.

Comment: @Lotzki What happens is it connects via AJAX. When it recieves the reply, it will redirect. Now the script has to send the email before replying AJAX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a background job.

To do this in the simplest way (note: not the best, but the simplest):

1. I'm assuming you're storing your registration details in some form of database. Add an extra column to flag that you need to send the validation email to this user.
2. In another script, check the database for any rows with this flag set, and send the email from there.
3. This second script will be triggered by a cronjob or similar, on a schedule of your choosing.

This way, users don't need to wait for that 10 seconds.

There are more efficient solutions that will cope better for larger scale sites, but I'm guessing that you don't yet need to know this, and that if I brought them into the equation it'd confuse matters. Look into Job Queues, if you want to know more.

Comment: I am just have some idea about cron jobs. Aren't the cron jobs triggered after some interval, which will again create the time lag. Also will the server allow for a job to be executed every 5-10 sec?

Comment: Well, I'm doing this mostly for the sake of learning. I have already done this with cron-jobs, but I want the mail to be sent immediately..

Comment: If you want the mail to be sent immediately, then you're going to have to live with the delay - and investigate to at least see if you can optimising the email sending. To answer @AbhishekBhatia - the server will allow for a cronjob to be executed every minute, any less than that would probably be a massive resource hog anyway.

Comment: @StephenOrr I've found a way, but it's a bit difficult with gzip :P

Comment: @StephenOrr And then I found fastcgi_finish_request() But I don't know if it will work with gzip if I choose to enable that in the future..